# Magento 2.3.5-p2: Show different title and alt for product img based on store

Tags: magento2.3, php, product-images, multistore, gallery-image

I'm trying to show a different **Title** and **Alt** depending on the store for the product page image.

For example on a english store (store id 1) **xyz.com/uk/** the Title and Alt would be

***title="English Title"
alt="English Alt"***

On a Japanese store (store id 2) **xyz.com/jp/** the Title and Alt would be

***title="Japanese Title"
alt="Japanese Alt"***

On a Danish store (store id 3) **xyz.com/dk/** the Title and Alt would be

***title="Danish Title"
alt="Danish Alt"***

The code I'm using is as follows, this doesn't change the title and alt depending on the store.

Location: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

```
<?php

$product = $block->getProduct();
$imageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

if (!$product->getImage() || $product->getImage() == 'no_selection') {
    $image = $imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');
} else {
    $image = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')
            ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
            ->setImageFile($product->getImage())
            ->getUrl();
}
?>
<div class="gallery-placeholder">
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="English Alt" title="English Title" >
</div>
```

I found a possible solution on getting the current store ID based on this [article](https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-current-store-id-in-magento-2/).

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
 
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
 
$storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

But I'm not able to put the above code together to do a what I assume is a if/else statement to show the title and alt based on the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it myself, the solution is as follows.

```
<?php

/** store ID **/

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
 
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
 
$storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();

/** image **/

$product = $block->getProduct();
$imageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

if (!$product->getImage() || $product->getImage() == 'no_selection') {
    $image = $imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');
} else {
    $image = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')
            ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
            ->setImageFile($product->getImage())
            ->getUrl();
}

/** Title/Alt **/

$storeid = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();

if ($storeid = 3) {
  $txt = "DK";
} elseif ($storeid = 2) {
  $txt = "JP";
} else {
  $txt = "EN";
}

?>


<div class="gallery-placeholder">
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $txt; ?>" title="<?php echo $txt; ?>" >
</div>
```